# What are common method for sensor feedback in teleoperated underwater ROV to close the control loop

Tags: control, sensors

I would like to know what are the common method to get sensor sensor feedback in teleoperated underwater  ROV to close the control loop. I mean does it use Velocity or Force and what sensor are used. I tried to use only IMU and get Velocity to control the UUV but velocity error accumulated over time and is not good. So any other options?

Thanks

Comment: why are you asking `how others do it?`, when you could be asking `how can I solve it?`

Comment: ok. Actulally wonted to know how can be solved. Any help? And is for underwater joystick teleoperated robot (underwater ROV)